# Passing commands to a function

Tags: bash, function, command, arguments

I'm having trouble while I try to pass some complex commands as arguments to a function.

```
    function executeCmd(){
    $1
    returnVal=$?
    if [[ $returnVal -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "Success"
    else
        echo "Failed"
    fi
}

executeCmd "ssh $USER@$IP "date && (ls | grep "something")""
```

I tried different quotations, escaping characters, but I'm missing something.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Abandon hope : this is the road to madness, (or hyper-extreme mastery of all quoting rules and corner cases. It can be a full time job). ;-) . Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to execute the command inside your status function; just call the following function *after* you call your command:

```
status () {
  if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
    echo "Success"
  else
    echo "Failure"
  fi
}
```

For example:

```
ssh $USER@$IP "date && (ls | grep \"something\")"; status
```

See [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for the details. (In essence, you are trying to put your command in the first positional parameter `$1` of your function.)

Comment: Thank you for the link. It helped me to understand some things.